# deploy a react with routers

Tags: reactjs, deployment, router

It works perfectly on localhost, but I can not deploy my react website with routers. Only the landing page is showing up, but not the others. Maybe that's because of the routers, here are several files that may go wrong. I figured the routing in main.js, with App.js file import it, and also the index.js file may go wrong. Thanks! (http://tianyiz8.github.io/personal-website)

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Particle from './component/particle/particle'
import {Layout, Header,Navigation,Drawer,Content} from 'react-mdl';
import Main from './pages/main'
import Footer from './component/footer/footer'
function App() {
  return (
    <div style={{height: '800px', position: 'relative'}}>
    <Layout fixedHeader>
        <Header className = "header-color" transparent title={<span><span style={{ color: '#ddd', marginBottom: '0'}}></span><strong>Navigation</strong></span>}>
          <Navigation>
            <a href="/landing">Profile</a>
            <a href="/aboutMe">About Me</a>
            <a href="/resume">Resume</a>
            <a href="/project">Project</a>
            <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
          </Navigation>
        </Header>
        <Drawer title="Go to ...">
            <Navigation>
                <a href="/landing">Profile</a>
                <a href="/aboutMe">About Me</a>
                <a href="/resume">Resume</a>
                <a href="/project">Project</a>
                <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
            </Navigation>
        </Drawer>
        <Content>
          <div className="page-content" />
          <Particle />
          <Main />
        </Content>
        <Footer/>
    </Layout>
</div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

main.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Landing from './landingpage/landingpage';
import AboutMe from './aboutme/aboutme';
import Project from './project/project';
import Contact from './contact/contact';
import Resume from './resume/resume';

const Main = () => (
  <BrowserRouter basename={ process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/' }>
    <div> 
      <Route exact path= '/' component={Landing} />
      <Route path= '/aboutMe' component={AboutMe} />
      <Route path= '/contact' component={Contact} />
      <Route path= '/project' component={Project} />
      <Route path= '/resume' component={Resume} />
      <Route path= '/landing' component={Landing} />
    </div> 
  </BrowserRouter>
)

export default Main;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import 'react-mdl/extra/material.css';
import 'react-mdl/extra/material.js';
import Landing from './pages/landingpage/landingpage';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
const routing = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div> 
      <Route exact path= {process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/'} component={Landing} />
      <Route path= {process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/aboutMe'} component={App} />
      <Route path= {process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/contact'} component={App} />
      <Route path= {process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/project'} component={App} />
      <Route path= {process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/resume'} component={App} />
      <Route path= {process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/landing'} component={App} />
    </div> 
  </BrowserRouter>
)
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root'), routing
);

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Comment: When you deploy are you running `npm run build` and then putting the build folder into a public_html folder?

Comment: i did npm run deploy, and i don't know about build folder or public_html folder

Answer (score 0):

So i put the  right inside the  in App.js and change  to  to fix the problem.